Why does hydrohalogenation usually proceed through protonation and not a pseudopericyclic reaction
Why does HX not add to alkenes via a pseudopericyclic reaction involving the alkene pi bond, a halogen lone pair, and the sigma bond of the hydrohalic acid?

Does HX look like BH3 to you? Still, I guess it's a valid question.

Where did I mention BH3¿

BH3 reacts in a way similar to you say, but is very different from hydrohalic acids. The stronger propensity for heterogenous cleavage of bond the less likely your scenario should be,

In a practical sense this comes from a lower transition state energy for typical HX additional mechanism compared to the alternative pseudopericyclic mechanism you propose. I did calculations with DFT/wB97X-D/6-31G* for a reaction between ethylene and $\ce{HCl}$ and it shows that the former is much more stable. From what I'm getting it's about $\ce{99.8 kJ/mol}$ which is a significant difference (as with these calculations it's the more negative energy calculation that represents the more stable state).


I would suspect this for a couple reasons. One, the TS ring probably has a lot of strain as depicted in the calculated TS and due to the electronegativity difference, the ring will also contain charged constituents which would may not favor an intermediate ring formation. Poor orbital overlap also plays a role here too I'd assume.
Now, I did the same calculations with hydroboration with $\ce{BH_3}$ instead of $\ce{HCl}$ and I got different results. I found that the ring formation was actually lower in energy by about $\ce{78.7 kJ/mol}$ (see below).


There seems to be better orbital overlap here and ultimately makes the cyclic TS more favorable it seems.

Nice! Note that BH3 is not directly comparable with HCl as hydrogen in the former is hydridic not protic.

What about a similar reaction with x2 instead of hx
